# vSphere 5.5 role permissions for viewing tags and tag assignments

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have a role assigned to me in vSphere and this role doesn't allow me to see any vmware tags but i know that tags are being used and are assigned to VMs.

In my personal lab, i'm able to reproduce this error but i'm having difficulty figuring out which permissions I need in order to query for tags and tag assignments.

Ideally, I'd like to not have the set/remove tag permissions.

Is this possible?

thanks.

Comment: When you said you cannot see any Vm Tags, was this through the Web Client GUI? or API/Python SDK? I can see the tags at the Webclient GUI but not the Python SDK.
These tags are migrated from custom attributes from earlier vCenter version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No specific permissions are needed but the permissions/role must be applied at the vCenter Host level and propagate down in order.

in my case, the permission was applied at the datacenter level prohibiting me from seeing any tags or assignments.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the `Global.Global tag` privilege along with the `vCenter Inventory Service.vCenter Inventory Service Tagging` privileges:

[image: vCenter Inventory Service Tagging]

See: [vSphere Security - ESXi 5.5 - VMware Documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-55-security-guide.pdf)

Comment: Hi @kce. Thanks for the response. Your post helped me investigate deeper. As it turns out, I didn't need any extra permissions but I did need the permissions applied at the "Vcenter Server" level as opposed to the datacenter level which it was previously at.